# Suppressing Unknown Publisher prompt which didn't used to appear

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on a Visual Studio .Net program for someone, and recently the program's been complaining that it's from an unknown publisher. I understand the correct thing to do here is sign it, but for reasons I won't go into that's not an option.

The thing is, the program's never done this in any earlier versions. As far as I know, I haven't changed anything that would have had an effect on security or whatever might be causing this issue. It doesn't do it on my system, either. The only major change I made since the last version in which it didn't say it was from an unknown publisher was adding SDL .Net for some graphics (previously had been generating bitmaps and using the picturebox element).

Answer (score 1):

Try to rollback your changes and check if it will complain. If you use [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) it shouldn't be a problem.

I think this is not because of your changes but because of some Windows security update.